# No such module 'FacebookCore' in swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am doing my own test app as part of my learning process in iOS development (using swift 5 on Xcode 11.0). I want to add login with Facebook on my login page but I keep getting *No such module 'FacebookCore'* when importing the library.

[image]

I followed the instructions on [developer.facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/implement-the-sdk) and tried to implement the SDK using cocoaPods and here is my Podfile

```
 # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'TestApp' do

  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TestApp
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

  target 'TestAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'TestAppUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

After executing pod install and adding the data in my info.plist as instructed by Facebook, I can clearly see that the framework has been linked in the *Link Binary With Libraries* section

[image]

But still, I can't seem to import FacebookCore nor FacebookLogin.

PS: I tried several solutions like:

1- Running the .xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj

2- Building the project even with the error being displayed (some said it would go away)

But none of them worked.

I suspect that the problem is in my Framework search path but why would it be wrong in the first place? so I may be wrong, here's a screenshot to my search path anyway:

[image]

Comment: Steps undertaken look fine. After pod install make sure you open the xcworkspace and not the xcodeproj file. Are you sure you created an iOS application and not a macOS application.

Comment: what you open ? workspace or project ?

Comment: The error remains when I try to run the app from the .xcworkspace file. And yes I'm positive it's an iOS and not a macOS app.

Comment: @jawadAli I tried both but I'm having the same error on both

Comment: okay let me check ... use .workspace

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So it turned out that I have to import *FBSDKCoreKit* instead of *FacebookCore* which was not mentioned in facebook's documentation. And it should be imported strictly using the **.xcworkspace** file which was also not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Still the solution in 2022.

Comment: "imported strictly using the .xcworkspace file" how do I do that?

Comment: Close the project and go to your project directory and open the .xcworkspace file (the white icon) and from there just add import FBSDKCoreKit to your class and it should work.

Answer (score 7):

Use FBSDKCoreKit instead of FacebookCore

This are the correct pods

```rb
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

and your imports should be

```swift
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
```

in previous version there was FacebookCoore as wrapper for the FBSDKCoreKit classes. It looks like Facebook has removed this since v5.x.

Answer (score -1):

The following should be your entries in Podfile

```rb
  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
```

and your imports should be

```swift
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin
```